# assign names to data frames columns in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames

```
# Create dummy data
df1<-data.frame( c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))
df2<-data.frame(c(5,6,7),c(4,5,6))

# Create a list
l<-list(df1, df2)
```

I would like to assign names to columns. As `l[[1]][,1]` gives me access to the first column, I thought I could assign 'names' as the first column name by:

```
l<-lapply(l, function(x)names(x[[1]][,1]<-"names"))
```

But this gives me an error

```
Error in x[[1]][, 1] <- "names" : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Edit: Added some dput
initial data

```
dput(lapply(head(results1, 2), head, 2))
list(structure(c(1.27679607834331, 1.05090175857491), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf"), "x")), structure(c(2.096687569578, 
2.19826038300833), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(c("..a15.pdf", 
"..a17.pdf"), "x")))
```

after trying to assign the name

```
dput(lapply(head(results1, 2), head, 2))
list(structure(c(1.27679607834331, 1.05090175857491), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(
    c("..a15.pdf", "..a17.pdf"), "names")), structure(c(2.096687569578, 
2.19826038300833), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(c("..a15.pdf", 
"..a17.pdf"), "names")))
```

Output:

```
results1[1]
[[1]]
                       names
..a15.pdf         1.27679608
..a17.pdf         1.05090176
..a18.pdf         1.51820192
..a21.pdf         2.30296037
..a2TTT.pdf       1.48568732
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the `names` of the dataframe:

```
l <- lapply(l, function(x) {names(x)[1] <-"names";x})
l
```

In `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

l <- map(l, ~.x %>% rename_with(~'names', 1))
```

---

From the updated data it seems you have list of matrices and the first column is actually rowname which you can convert to a column and name it.

```
lapply(results1, function(x) {
  mat <- cbind.data.frame(names = rownames(x), x)
  rownames(mat) <- NULL
  mat
})

#[[1]]
#      names    x
#1 ..a15.pdf 1.28
#2 ..a17.pdf 1.05

#[[2]]
#      names   x
#1 ..a15.pdf 2.1
#2 ..a17.pdf 2.2
```

Comment: thanks it works on the example I provided, so I accepted the answer. But when I try on my original list, it appears that 'names' is assigned as an attribute to the first variable in the first column (I have 22 variables) so when I try l[[1]] it gives me the two columns with no name for the first column and then this text:  attr(,"names")
 [1] "names" NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
...........
[19] NA      NA      NA      NA    . If you have an idea why is this happening it would be great otherwise I'll try to figure out myself.

Comment: It means that you have a different structure in your actual data. Can you provide some more information about the data? What does `lengths(l)` and `class(l[[1]])` return?

Comment: your second suggestions gives me this error on my list Error in UseMethod("rename_with") : 
  no applicable method for 'rename_with' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: I think this might work. Try `l <- lapply(l, function(x) {colnames(x)[1] <-"names";x})`

Comment: length(results1)
[1] 462
> class(results1[[1]])
[1] "matrix" "array"

Comment: your second suggestion gives me the same output as the first one. I mean the suggestion that you posted in comments. I guess I'll post another question with a dput of my data.

Comment: So `l <- lapply(l, function(x) {colnames(x)[1] <-"names";x})` doesn't work either? That's strange. Can you edit your post with the actual data? Copy the output of  `dput(lapply(head(l, 2), head, 2))`

Comment: Added dput from initial data and as a result of applying the function

Comment: I already see the 1st column name as `names` in the `dput`. Isn't that what you are looking for ?

Comment: probably my first column is not a column then? I see names but it is what I think is the second column. I'll add what I see in my question.

Comment: That is not a column, it is rownames of the matrix. What do you want to do of them? Do you want to keep it as first column or you want to remove it?

Comment: I want it as a first column. I thought I did it by  results1<-lapply(results1, function(x)cbind(x, names=rownames(x)))

Comment: I have updated the answer which you can use on the initial data. This will create rownames as a new column, convert matrix to dataframe and remove rownames. Matrix can hold data of only one type so if you create a new column with names it will change the numbers to characters as well, hence I changed that to dataframe.

Comment: I've tried it. Unfortunately it gives an error Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 22.

Comment: Hmmm....Can't reproduce this on the data that you have shared.